# Split an array into arrays

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and would like to know if there is a better way to solve the following problem.

I have an array that looks like this:

`[6, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3]`

I'd like to turn it into this:

```
[ [1,1], [2,2], [3,3,3], [4], [], [6,6] ]
```

This is my current solution (again, I'm new to Ruby):

```
def split_array_into_arrays(array)
  max_num = array.max
  arrays = Array.new(max_num) { Array.new }

  array.each do |num|
    arrays[num-1] << num
  end

  arrays
end

arrays = split_array_into_arrays([6, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3])
puts arrays.inspect
```

Produces:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4], [], [6, 6]]
```

*Note: I realize I am not handling possible errors.*

How might an experienced Ruby developer implement this?

Comment: why would you need empty arrays where there is no number? e.g. 5

Comment: Normally `group_by` would be sufficient, but it appears you want to have an explicit empty array for the missing `5`?

Comment: Yup.. that's why I'm asking. In order to give a good answer you need details like this. Maybe `array.sort.group_by{|x| x}.values` is enough for you

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, for this *contrived example*, I would like "missing" numbers to be represented by empty arrays. I'm simply using this stuff to better understand Ruby - this isn't code I'm going to use for anything serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ar = [6, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3]

(1..ar.max).map{|n| [n]*ar.count(n)}
# => [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4], [], [6, 6]]
```